# Access Violation on Accessing a UserSession in Intraweb

Tags: delphi, access-violation, delphi-xe5, intraweb

I'm new to IntraWeb and have a problem.
In order to implement a Login Form, i stored Datasets in the Usersession.
But when it comes to access the Datasets i get an Access Violation Error.
I figured out, that the Useresession is not created. Now i'm a bit confused, because in the Intraweb Documentary it is said, that the Usersession is created automatically by the ServerController.

I access (respectively want to) the Dataset like this
 `UserSession.Dataset.open;`

I use the IntraWeb Trial included in Rad Studio XE5. May that be the Problem?
In case, that this is not the Problem, how can i create a Usersession manually?

Thank you very much

[Edit 13.4.16]

The problem was the Evaluation Version I used. After installing the Full Version my problem vanished. They changed their Usersession.create procedure by adding another Parameter. So make sure you use the actual Version if u have the same Problem:
Thanks for all the responses

Comment: Is UsserSession created?

Comment: No.
Somehow the create action didn't get triggered.
I made a Breakpoint at this Function in the ServerController

`procedure TIWServerController.IWServerControllerBaseNewSession(
  ASession: TIWApplication; var VMainForm: TIWBaseForm);`

but while Debugging this procedure was never called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the 'data' inside session

```
procedure TIWServerController.IWServerControllerBaseNewSession(
  ASession: TIWApplication; var VMainForm: TIWAppForm);
begin
  ASession.Data := TUserSession.Create;
end;
```

be aware that in this example

> TUserSession

is an user defined class

```
type
  TUserSession = class
  public
    UserCount: Integer;
  end;
```

take a look at this tutorial which explains how the sessions management is done in IW - http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+IV+Delphi+the+Internet+and+a+.NET+Preview/Chapter+21+Web+Programming+with+IntraWeb/Building+IntraWeb+Applications/

or consult the [technical documentation](http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/docs/Develop/Sessions/index.aspx) provided by atozed.

Comment: The Atozed Documentation  says _A users session is automatically managed by IntraWeb. When a new session is started IntraWeb will create a new instance of a TIWApplication (or IWApplication in Visual Studio .NET) for the user and track it automatically._
Do i have to create it again?
When i look at the first link and the given example, i see, that they doesn't explizit call the 'create' procedure.

Comment: You have create the app using the wizzard? On the other hand, you say that you are creating a login form, and I suspect that your controller has not finished doing it's job. But without the source code of your app this are just suppositions...

Comment: Yes i've used the Wizzard. What do you mean by "controller has not finishing doing it's job"?
I didn't change the Code from the Servercontroller. In Fact i thought about accessing to early too. So i created a "Welcome" Screen where you can press a button to get to the Login.
If i get it right, the Servercontroller should've created a Usersession by then.
This "welcome" screen ist initialized as main
'  TiwfStart.SetAsMainForm;'
and except of the onClick procedure it is identic to the generated Unit from the Wizzard. 
Shall i post the Code of the Site in the main Question? Ty for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding just a comment, apparently I need more points for that.
The answer will be found if you go into the response given by RBA, but here is the short form:

IW does create and manage the user session automatically.  The TIWUserSession, however, is only your part of that.  In order to have your own data in the session, .Create the TIWUserSession and add it as the .Data of the session.  In IWServerControllerBaseNewSession do this with:

```
  ASession.Data := TIWUserSession.Create(nil, ASession);
```

Note that the ASession parameter of the procedure is the session managed by IW.

In order to access your TIWUserSession, create a procedure in ServerController:

```
function UserSession: TIWUserSession;
begin
    Result := TIWUserSession(WebApplication.Data);
end;
```

Expose that procedure in the interface section.

Dan

Comment: The code created automatically looks like this:
` ASession.Data := TIWUserSession.Create(nil);`
I only have one argument for this Procedure.
I read somewhere that this is because i use an old Version of intraweb and in fact i'm using Version 14.0.0. 
I now tested my requirements without using the UserSession and will buy the full Version soon. 
Then i have an actual Version and hope that this will do the trick.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I think for 14.0.0 the automagic code creation uses the older form.  They changed the code creation at 14.0.13.  See: [link](http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/history/XIV/index.EN.aspx)    The older form was still supposed to work, as I understand it.  Also see [link](http://docs.atozed.com/docs.dll/development/Migrating%20to%20IntraWeb%20XIV.html#OnNewSession)

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that we might be "solving the wrong problem".

You indicated that this occurred when you were implementing a login form.  You also indicated that a break set in WServerControllerBaseNewSession() did not hit.

In ServerController, do you have "AuthBeforeNewSession" set to True?  If so, set it to False and see if the behavior changes.

Dan

Comment: "AuthBeforeNewSession" is set to false.